# Проблема в регулярке?

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения

Ничего не выводится, даже ошибок нет. Хотя судя по https://regex101.com/r/daKgi9/1 все должно работать. Что я делаю не так?

### test.py

```py
import re
with open("test.html", "r") as f:
    contents = f.read()
    pattern = r"Elapsed\sTime:\D+(.+?)<\/font>Last\sCalled\sNumber:\D+(\d{5,})@gw0<\/font>\D+(\d{5,})<\/font>.+Line\sVoltage:\D+(.+?)<\/font>.+PSTN\sState:\D+(R.+?)<\/font>"
    match = re.search(pattern, contents)
    if match:
        print(match.group(1))
        print(match.group(2))
        print(match.group(3))
        print(match.group(4))
        print(match.group(5))
```

### test.html

```html
Elapsed Time:</td><td><font color="darkblue">16 days and 12:42:31</font>Last Called Number:</td><td><font color="darkblue">67678799989@gw0</font></td><td>Last Caller Number:</td><td><font color="darkblue">876868856454</font></td></tr><tr bgcolor="#dcdcdc"><td>Hook State:</td><td><font color="darkblue">On</font></td><td>Line Voltage:</td><td><font color="darkblue">21 (V)</font></td></tr><tr bgcolor="#dcdcdc"><td>PSTN State:</td><td><font color="darkblue">Ringing</font></td><td>VoIP Tone:</td><td><font color="darkblue"></font>
```

Comment: Код делает ровно то, что в нем написано. А что он по вашему должен делать вместо этого?

Comment: Не совсем то. Вопрос отредактирован.

Comment: Разбирать `html` регулярками изначально плохая затея. Лучше разбирать его именно как `html` специальными библиотеками. А потом уже регулярками, если нужно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Elapsed\sTime.*?<font.*?>(.*?)<\/font>(.|\r|\n)+Last\sCalled\sNumber:.*<font.*>(.*?)\@.*?<\/font>.*?<font.*?>(.*?)<\/font>(.|\r|\n)+Line\sVoltage:.*<font.*>(.*?)<\/font>(.|\r|\n)+PSTN\sState:.*?<font.*?>(.*?)<\/font>(.|\r|\n)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

> Ничего не выводится

Уточните проблему. Откопипастил Вашу программу и исходные данные. Всё великолепно выводится:

```
bash-5.0$ python test.py
16 days and 12:42:31
67678799989
876868856454
21 (V)
Ringing
bash-5.0$
```

Либо Вы не туда смотрите, либо неправильно скопировали исходные данные.

Comment: Да, действительно, не тот файл скопирровал. В вопросе изменил ссылку на regex101. Между </font> и Last Called Number: может быть сколь угодно много разного текста, регулярка работает как нужно, если после </font> несколько раз добавить D+\d*\D*\d*\D. Как избежать многократных повторов D+\d*\D*\d*\D ?

Comment: Почему у Вас первая 'D' без обратного слэша?